# Rails rendered object.attribute with spaces truncated in jquery data attribute

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a DOM element in my Rails view and I want to access the data attribute using Jquery.

Rails View example:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <a class="comment" data-user_comment = <%= comment.content %> ><%= comment.updated_at %> - <%= comment.content %></a>
<% end %>
```

JQuery example:

```
$('.comment').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("data-comment"));
})
```

This is pretty standard, but my issue is if the data attribute has spaces, the alert only shows the first word.  Rails doesn't seem to be rendering comment.content as a string, is this normal behaviour for Rails or am I missing something big??!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give it as  :

```
<a class="comment" data-user_comment = "<%= comment.content %>" ><%= comment.updated_at %> - <%= comment.content %></a>
```

Missing quotes. On missing quotes only the first word is taken and the remaining is taken as a different attrribute.

So on using fire bug you can see that it your comment had : "Lorem Ipusem" the value of data-user_comment is "Lorem" and Ipusem itself becomes an attr with blank value (Ipusem = "").